# Make returning linker error although library files are in their place

Tags: c++, makefile

My linker says it can not find library files allthough they exist and the path is set correctly.
I run make and I have my makefile`print the`LDFLAGS`:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib
```

This is my compiler call:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wall -fPIC -isystem /usr/local/include -fsigned-char -D_USE_EMBEDDED_         -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a5 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv4-d16 -pipe  -funroll-loops  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -pipe -Wl,--dynamic-list-cpp-typeinfo objfile1.o objfile2.o archive1.a archive2.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-1_49 -lboost_program_options-gcc46-mt-1_49 -lboost_regex-gcc46-mt-1_49 -lboost_system-gcc46-mt-1_49 -Wl,-Bdynamic -l:libxalan-c.so.111 -l:libxerces-c-3.1.so -lstdc++   -lpthread  -ldl -o Outfile.linux-arm
```

But for the last 6 libraries I get this kind of linker error:

```
   /home/myhome/devel/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-1_49
```

When I check my library path `/usr/local/lib/` I do find these files:

```
libboost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-1_49.a
libboost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-1_49.so -> libboost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-1_49.so.1.49.0
libboost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-1_49.so.1.49.0
```

How come make gives this error? Everything should be in its place!
Thanks!

Comment: You elide the most important part of the linker line.  It's find that you print `LDFLAGS`, but inside the `(...)` in your compiler call example above, do you actually _see_ `-L/usr/local/lib?  If so, you can try adding `-Wl,-v` to the link line to enable verbose mode in the linker which should give you some details about what it's looking for, and where.

Comment: I added the whole line. Don't find the Path to the libraries though.

Comment: Ok I checked LDFLAGS later in the makefile right before the linker call and appearently it changed. Doesnt have the library path anymore..

Comment: Well, there's your problem then.